# Required Long parameter 'flightId' is not present]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

*I am facing There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400). error and in spring log below message is appearing. **Required Long parameter 'flightId' is not present]***
*Any idea what is wrong here?* I check all files thoroughly but couldn't figure out where is problem. In controller or Jsp?
*Below are all java and jsp files.*

---

```
**Abstract Entities**




package com.bharat.flightreservation.entities;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}



------------------------------------

**Flight Controller**




package com.bharat.flightreservation.controllers;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.bharat.flightreservation.entities.Flight;
import com.bharat.flightreservation.repos.FlightRepository;

@Controller
public class FlightController {
    
    @Autowired
    FlightRepository flightRepository;
    
    @RequestMapping("findFlights")
    public String findFlights(@RequestParam("from") String from, @RequestParam("to") String to, 
            @RequestParam("departureDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy") Date departureDate, 
            ModelMap modelMap) {
        
        List<Flight> flights = flightRepository.findFlights(from,to,departureDate);
        modelMap.addAttribute("flights", flights);
        return "displayFlights";
    }

}


----------------------------

**Reservaction Controller**




package com.bharat.flightreservation.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.bharat.flightreservation.entities.Flight;
import com.bharat.flightreservation.repos.FlightRepository;

@Controller
public class ReservationController {
    
    @Autowired
    FlightRepository flightRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/showCompleteReservation")
    public String showCompleteReservation(@RequestParam ("flightId") Long flightId,ModelMap modelMap) {
        Flight flight= flightRepository.getOne(flightId);
                modelMap.addAttribute("flight", flight);
        return "completeReservation";
    
    }
    
}


------------------------------------------

**Display Flights jsp**





<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@page isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Flight Details</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Flights:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Airlines</th>
<th>Departure City</th>
<th>Arrival City</th>
<th>Departure Time</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${flights}" var="flight">
<tr>
<td>${flight.operatingAirlines}</td>
<td>${flight.departureCity}</td>
<td>${flight.arrivalCity}</td>
<td>${flight.estimatedDepartureTime}</td>
<td><a href="showCompleteReservation?id=${flight.id}">Select</a></td>
</tr>

</c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>


-------------------------------------------

**Complete Reservation jsp**




<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@page isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Complete Reservation</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Complete Reservation</h2>
Airline: ${flight.operatingAirlines}<br/>
Airline: ${flight.departureCity}<br/>
Airline: ${flight.arrivalCity}<br/>

<form action="completeReservation" method="post">
<pre>
<h2>Passenger Details:</h2>
First Name:<input type="text" name="passengerFirstName"/>
Last Name:<input type="text" name="passengerLastName"/>
Email:<input type="text" name="passengerEmail"/>
Phone:<input type="text" name="passengerPhone"/>
<h2>Card Details:</h2>

Name on the Card:<input type="text" name="nameOnTheCard"/>
Card Number:<input type="text" name="cardNumber"/>
Expiry Date:<input type="text" name="expirationDate"/>
Three Digit Sec Code:<input type="text" name="securityCode"/>

<input type="hidden" name="flightId" value="${flight.id}"/>
<input type="submit" value="confirm"/>
</pre>
</form>
</body>
</html>


------------------------------

**Flight**





package com.bharat.flightreservation.entities;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;



@Entity
public class Flight extends AbstractEntity {

    private String flightNumber;
    private String operatingAirlines;
    private String departureCity;
    private String arrivalCity;
    private Date dateOfDeparture;
    private Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime;

    

    public String getFlightNumber() {
        return flightNumber;
    }

    public void setFlightNumber(String flightNumber) {
        this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
    }

    public String getOperatingAirlines() {
        return operatingAirlines;
    }

    public void setOperatingAirlines(String operatingAirlines) {
        this.operatingAirlines = operatingAirlines;
    }

    public String getDepartureCity() {
        return departureCity;
    }

    public void setDepartureCity(String departureCity) {
        this.departureCity = departureCity;
    }

    public String getArrivalCity() {
        return arrivalCity;
    }

    public void setArrivalCity(String arrivalCity) {
        this.arrivalCity = arrivalCity;
    }

    public Date getDateOfDeparture() {
        return dateOfDeparture;
    }

    public void setDateOfDeparture(Date dateOfDeparture) {
        this.dateOfDeparture = dateOfDeparture;
    }

    public Timestamp getEstimatedDepartureTime() {
        return estimatedDepartureTime;
    }

    public void setEstimatedDepartureTime(Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime) {
        this.estimatedDepartureTime = estimatedDepartureTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Flight [flightNumber=" + flightNumber + ", operatingAirlines=" + operatingAirlines + ", departureCity="
                + departureCity + ", arrivalCity=" + arrivalCity + ", dateOfDeparture=" + dateOfDeparture
                + ", estimatedDepartureTime=" + estimatedDepartureTime + "]";
    }

}


----------------------------------------

**Reservation** 




package com.bharat.flightreservation.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Reservation extends AbstractEntity {

    private Boolean checkedIn;
    private int numberOfBags;
    @OneToOne
    private Passenger passenger;
    @OneToOne
    private Flight flight;

    

    public Boolean getCheckedIn() {
        return checkedIn;
    }

    public void setCheckedIn(Boolean checkedIn) {
        this.checkedIn = checkedIn;
    }

    public int getNumberOfBags() {
        return numberOfBags;
    }

    public void setNumberOfBags(int numberOfBags) {
        this.numberOfBags = numberOfBags;
    }

    public Passenger getPassenger() {
        return passenger;
    }

    public void setPassenger(Passenger passenger) {
        this.passenger = passenger;
    }

    public Flight getFlight() {
        return flight;
    }

    public void setFlight(Flight flight) {
        this.flight = flight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Reservation [checkedIn=" + checkedIn + ", numberOfBags=" + numberOfBags + ", passenger=" + passenger
                + ", flight=" + flight + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: * It will probably help to add "JPA" to your question title, and also add a JPA tag.  People with JPA knowledge might be able to help.
* It's confusing that your entity class has "Abstract" in its name, yet it's not an abstract class.
* I suggest exercising your JPA entities outside of Spring Boot.  I would try to doing a DB insert and a read.  Doing these tests outside of Spring Boot should let you see the error details, such as a stackdump, more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call your endpoint with `id` request param

```
<td><a href="showCompleteReservation?id=${flight.id}">Select</a></td>
```

But in your controller we can see `flightId`

```
public String showCompleteReservation(@RequestParam ("flightId") Long flightId)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thank Dear It worked after changing it to id in method.**

---

```
@RequestMapping("/showCompleteReservation")
    public String showCompleteReservation(@RequestParam ("id") Long id,ModelMap modelMap) {
        Flight flight= flightRepository.getOne(id);
                modelMap.addAttribute("flight", flight);
        return "completeReservation";
    
    }
```